# Django Queryset only method and foreign keys real fields ('_id')

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

In order to minimize bugs in competitive access to instances of django models, I'm using "only" method of QuerySet. For example, I have models like:

```
    #models.py
    class MyModel1(models.Model):
         ...

    class MyModel2(models.Model):
         field_1 = models.ForeignKey(MyModel1)
         ...
```

I'm using "only" in this way:

```
    instances = list(MyModel2.objects.filter(...).only('id'))
```

Will field "field_1_id" of instances be loaded at this moment (not 'field_1', exactly 'field_1_id')?

Answer (score 1):

only() method loads only the id of  model MyModel2.

Comment: Can you point me the line of source (or line in documentation), from which this will be clear?

Comment: you can refer  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.QuerySet.only

Answer (score 0):

Check out using the [values_list()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) method, which can return a list of values if you have only one field you need and you pass it *flat = True*:

```
instances = MyModel2.objects.filter(...).values_list('id', flat=True)
```

Comment: values_list after iteration DOES NOT return instances of models. Of course it's critical to get instances to not to break API.